# Why when I make this function return its value, the function repeats itself infinitely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods, return

This is my code, and in the line, I put a commentary about the `return` that makes this problem.

```py
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(m_x, m_y):
    print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format((m_x, m_y)))

def on_click(m_x, m_y, button, pressed):

    #print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',(m_x, m_y)))

    if(pressed):
        print("Pressed")
    else:
        print("( x = "+ str(m_x) + ", y = " + str(m_y) + " )")
        return(m_x, m_y) #this is the return

    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def on_scroll(m_x, m_y, dm_x, dm_y):
    print('Scrolled {0} at {1}'.format(
        'down' if dy < 0 else 'up',
        (m_x, m_y)))

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll)
A_coord_x, A_coord_y = mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll)
#listener.start()


print (A_coord_x)
print (A_coord_y)
```

The only thing I want is that after giving a click the coordinates are saved in the variables `A_coord_x` and `A_coord_y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer for you. this will release the `listener` and get you the coordinates in `A_coord_x` and `A_coord_y`

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

A_coord_x, A_coord_y = 0, 0


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global A_coord_x, A_coord_y
    if pressed:
        A_coord_x, A_coord_y = x, y
        print('{0} at {1}'.format(
            'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
            (x, y)))
        return x,y
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    coords = listener.join()


print ('X coordinates :',A_coord_x)
print ('Y coordinates :',A_coord_y)
```

output:

```
Pressed at (1211, 400)
X coordinates : 1211
Y coordinates : 400
```

Comment: sure Please @ElectrisikVocal

Answer (score 0):

`on_click()` is an event handler, you can't return values from it, the return False statement just stops the listener. Just call a set_coordinates(x,y) function from within the handler and you should get your intended result.

Maybe also take a look at the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html), there is an example on how to work with the mouse.listener